# How can I sum the arguments of a function [function signature given, 1024 Int arguments...]

Tags: haskell

I'm Trying to figure out how I can Sum up the Arguments of a Function which has a given signature `sum :: Int -> ... -> Int` with 1024 Int arguments...

Clever Currying / Recursion is surely the deal I just can't grasp how to even start.

Comment: While this *could* be done with typeclass hackery like printf uses, it seems like a terrible idea to have such a function. Why do you need it?

Comment: It is part of a "Tutorial" trying to test our understanding. Its not meant to be practical!

Comment: There's an interesting challenge on Codewars about this, which I did recently, which comes with a few hints (I would never have been able to complete it without them, and even with them it was hard work): https://www.codewars.com/kata/599aed42b9712e1afe000014 As others have said, I'm not sure what the practical use is, since it's easy to sum a list.

Answer (score 7):

The fact that it's 1024 is probably meant to be a clue that you should
build up to it in powers of two.  Here's a solution as far as 16 which
you can extend.

It's using a continuation passing style as a way to let you have one
function consume some arguments and then another consume some more.
To see what's going on, try calculating out a small example by hand,
say `add4 id 1 2 3 4`.

```
add2 :: (Int -> a) -> Int -> Int -> a
add2 k x y = k (x + y)

add4 :: (Int -> a) -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> a
add4 k = add2 (add2 (add2 k))

-- type signatures omitted from now on...
add8 k = add4 (add4 (add2 k))

add16 k = add8 (add8 (add2 k))

f = add16 id
```

And now you can do:

```
>f 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
136
```

I could also have written the functions more pointfree, for example:

```
add8 = add4 . add4 . add2
```

Comment: `doubleArgs f = f . f . add2 -- if f has type (Int-> a) -> (Int ->)^n a, the three parts respectively add n, (n-1), 1 args` then do `sq f = f . f` and `twoToNineArgs = (sq . sq . sq . sq . sq . sq . sq . sq) doubleArgs` to get `f = twoToNineArgs add2 id`

Comment: @DanRobertson Perhaps this would be less inscrutable if you expanded it into an answer of more than one sentence. In this very small margin it is hard to understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: so, `addJ . addK . ... . addN` will handle `J + (K-1) + ... + (N-1)` arguments.

Answer (score 5):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
class SumArgs a where sumArgs :: Int -> a
instance SumArgs Int where sumArgs = id
instance SumArgs a => SumArgs (Int -> a) where sumArgs m n = sumArgs (m+n)

sumFourExample :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
sumFourExample = sumArgs
```

In ghci:

```
> sumFourExample 2 3 4 5
14
```

Comment: Thank you, nice solution. Is it possible to do that in a simpler, less advanced way too? Maybe considering that the signature is fixed? Its the second week of my Functional Programming course so Im asking myself if could really be that advanced (but nothing can shock me anymore)

Comment: @user1836966 It doesn't get much simpler than a single typeclass with two instances. You could either sit and type for a long time or cook up an editor macro to finish off the `...`s in `f a1 a2 a3 ... a1024 = a1 + a2 + ... + a1024`, I guess.

Comment: @user1836966 Are you sure you don't want to just add up a list that contains an arbitrary number of `Int`s (including a list of 1024 `Int`s)? That is *significantly* easier/less painful to do than making a function of 1024 arguments.

Comment: Im getting an Error when Executing your code in ghci: 'error:
    * Illegal instance declaration for `SumArgs a'
        (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
         where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
         and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
         Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    * In the instance declaration for `SumArgs a'
   |
21 | instance SumArgs a  where sumArgs m n = sumArgs (m+n)
   |

' Do you know why? I Dont get it, Im a Haskell beginner and not familiar with classes yet... Thanks!

Comment: @user1836966 To enable `FlexibleInstances` in ghci, you must use `:set -XFlexibleInstances` instead of the `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` pragma used in this answer.